# Paste into a Specific Column - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good afternoon, I made this script. 
But, it's pasting in column A and I need to paste it in column E.
How can I do this?

```
function Teste() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var source = ss.getRange('Entradas!B9:H29');

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('BD');


    var lastFilledRowInColumnE = getLastPopulatedRow(destSheet.getRange('E:K').getValues());


    var destRange = destSheet.getRange(lastFilledRowInColumnE+1,1);
    source.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true});

};
```

Comment: In your current script, the values are copied to column "A - G". For this situation, you want to copy the values to the column "E - K". If my understanding is correct, how about modifying from ``var destRange = destSheet.getRange(lastFilledRowInColumnE+1,1)`` to ``var destRange = destSheet.getRange(lastFilledRowInColumnE+1,5)``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem could be with the line:

```
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(lastFilledRowInColumnE+1,1);
```

There are a few different `getRange` functions. If you only supply two arguments, you are calling the [`getRange(row, column)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)) version. You are pasting into the row "`lastFilledRowInColumnE+1`" and column 1, which is A.

You may simply need to write "5" instead of "1" to represent column "E".